# Spark reading WARC file with custom InputFormat

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark

I need to process a .warc file through Spark but I can't seem to find a straightforward way of doing so. I would prefer to use Python and to not read the whole file into an RDD through `wholeTextFiles()` (because the whole file would be processed at a single node(?)) therefore it seems like the only/best way is through a custom Hadoop `InputFormat` used with `.hadoopFile()` in Python.

However, I could not find an easy way of doing this. To split a .warc file into entries is as simple as splitting on `\n\n\n`; so how can I achieve this, without writing a ton of extra (useless) code as shown in various "tutorials" online? Can it be done all in Python?

i.e., How to split a warc file into entries without reading the whole thing with `wholeTextFiles`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If delimiter is `\n\n\n` you can use `textinputformat.record.delimiter`

```
sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
  path ,
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat',
  'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
  'org.apache.hadoop.io.Text',
  conf={'textinputformat.record.delimiter': '\n\n\n'}
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation for this function is not very good. Do you know what the  Tuples in the resulting RDD (LongWritable,Text) consist of?